# python using argparse.ArgumentParser method

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

I've tried to learn how `argparse.ArgumentParser` works and I've write a couple lines for that :

```
global firstProduct
global secondProduct 
myparser=argparse.ArgumentParser(description='parser test')
myparser.add_argument("product1",help="enter product1",dest='product_1')
myparser.add_argument("product2",help="enter product2",dest='product_2')

args=myparser.parse_args()

firstProduct=args.product_1
secondProduct=args.product_2
```

I just want to that when User run this script with 2 parameters  my code assign them to `firstProduct` and `secondProduct` respectively. However it doesn’t work. Is there anyone to tell me why? thanks in advance

Comment: You should describe the error, not just say 'it doesn't work'.  The error message: "ValueError: dest supplied twice for positional argument" is important.  unutbu's answer addresses that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Omit the `dest` parameter when using a positional argument. The name supplied for the positional argument will be the name of the argument:

```
import argparse
myparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='parser test')
myparser.add_argument("product_1", help="enter product1")
myparser.add_argument("product_2", help="enter product2")

args = myparser.parse_args()
firstProduct = args.product_1
secondProduct = args.product_2
print(firstProduct, secondProduct)
```

Running `% test.py foo bar` prints

```
('foo', 'bar')
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Here is 2 more question. 1) writing product_1 with double quates or single differs ? 2) what is the difference between positional argument and the others ?

Comment: The `dest` parameter can be used with the `optionals` (ones starting with `-`)

Comment: (1) There is no difference in the result if you specify strings with single
quotes or double quotes. Having both options simply helps with quoting quotes:
`"'"` or `'"'` for example. (2) When the first argument to `add_argument` starts with
`-` or `--`, it is an optional argument. Without the dash, it is a positional
argument. Positional arguments are recognized by their position: `test.py foo bar`
interprets foo as being in the first position, so it is associated with the
first positional argument, `product_1`

Comment: a strange behavior to me that looks a bug. if I use a character '-' into a positional parameter name, form example `'my-name'` it doesn't look to be changed as a dest with '-' replaced to '_' ; since it cannot be used explicitly `'dest'` param, there is no way to access the value!
If i use str() to dump `'args'` returned, I obtain something lie `Namespace( ... , my-name=1, ....)` but i wouldn't be possibile to python to accept such a variable! In fact is a syntax error to write `args.my-name=xxxx`

Comment: @bzimage: You could access the value using `args.__dict__['my-name']`.

Answer (score 15):

In addition to [unutbu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18335770/1677912), you may also use the `metavar` attribute in order to make the destination variable and the variable name that appears in the help menus different, as shown in [this link](https://code.google.com/p/argparse/issues/detail?id=65).

For example if you do:

```
myparser.add_argument("firstProduct", metavar="product_1", help="enter product1")
```

You will have the argument available for you in `args.firstProduct` but have it listed as `product_1` in the help.