# Trying to specify command line arguments and can't figure it out - not entirely sure what 'dest' and 'store' do in optparse

Tags: python, bash, parsing, command-line

So I'm trying to get my program to do take the command line arguments and use it in my script. I read `argparse` and the `optparse` documentation and I'm still lost.
What I'm trying to do is have my code execute this on the command line:

```
./program <-p port> <-s> [required1] [required2]
```

The -p is optional, and I want to make the port a variable in my script, like so:

```
server_address = ('some server name', **port**)
```

I thought that that's what `store` and `dest` would do... as in `store` would take the `port` argument and `dest` would be the variable name and I could call it like `program.port`. It doesn't work this way, however, and I can't find or decipher explanations for what exactly store and dest do.

I'm new to Python, so this might not be a well-formed question.

Comment: I'm gonna assume you meant `parser.add_argument('-p', '--port', type=int)`, which I just tried, and didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, following the documentation:

1. You create a parser

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Some helpful text about what your function does')
```

2. You add arguments, optional ones have '-'s before hand, see below

```py
parser.add_argument('-p', '--port', type=int, default=0, help='port')
parser.add_argument('-s', help='I don\'t know what this is')
parser.add_argument('required_1')  # Note the lack of dashes
parser.add_argument('required_2')
```

3. You need to parse the arguments with a function call

```py
args = parser.parse_args()
```

4. This creates a [namespace object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-namespace-object) which you can then access your variables from, see below

```py
port = args.port
or
port = vars(args)['port']
req1 = args.required_1
req2 = args.required_2
etc...
```

For more information on namespace objects, checkout this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828277/what-is-a-namespace-object)

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! Out of all of the resources I tried to look at, this is the most helpful and clear one I've seen. I did more digging and found this, as well, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335687/python-using-argparse-argumentparser-method, but I appreciate your answer a lot.

Comment: You're welcome, if this answers your question, please remember to accept the answer! :)